# How to animate some property of custom `QQuickItem` based class using C++?

Tags: c++, qt, animation, qtquick2, qquickitem

As we know, Scene Graph has special multithreaded v-sync aware render technology.
Also QtQuick has special C++ classes specified with `QSG*` prefix names and are strongly recommended to be used only those classes inside `QQuickItem`.

So is it ok to use regular (old?) C++ Animation Framework classes such as `QPropertyAnimation` in `QQuickItem` classes?

How I can animate some properties inside `QQuickItem` using `C++` without breaking Scene Graph performance/rules?

Thank you